# $\Delta ABC\sim\Delta EDC$: $\overline{AB}$ is parallel to $\overline{DE}$ is true. How is $\overline{AE}$ is not perpendicular to $\overline{BD}$?

Tags: geometry, triangles

In the figure below, $\Delta ABC\sim\Delta EDC$. Which of the following must be true?

1. $\overline{AE}$ is parallel to $\overline{BD}$
2. $\overline{AE}$ is perpendicular to $\overline{BD}$
3. $\overline{AB}$ is parallel to $\overline{DE}$
4. $\overline{AB}$ is perpendicular to $\overline{DE}$

[image]

I can see that $\overline{AB}$ is parallel to $\overline{DE}$. However, $\overline{AE}$ perpendicular to $\overline{BD}$ seems feasible too. However, the correct answer is said to be only option 3. The reasoning for option 2 being wrong has been mentioned as:

> The answer may result from visual inspection of the diagram. The line segments appear to be perpendicular, but need not be, given the information provided.

How are these lines not perpendicular? What am I missing?

Comment: What is your reason behind them being perpendicular?

Comment: Because the lines form four right angles.

Comment: In this context, angles are not "right" unless explicitly marked such

Comment: "That's how they get you!"

Comment: Ask Landuros' comment/question another way.  Suppose you (randomly) re-produce the drawing, so that the constraints are satisfied, and so that A-B parallel to D-E.  Are you able to draw the diagram **without** A-E and B-D being perpendicular?  If so, then that is a counter-example, so the assertion of them **having** to be perpendicular must be false.

Comment: I still don’t understand why not?

Comment: Where does it say they formed right angles? Couldn't one of the angles formed be $89^\circ$ since it's not specified?

Comment: I’m still confused. HELP ME!

Comment: You don't know that they're 90 degrees apart. The angles could be at any angle between 0 and 180 degrees apart, therefore it is not true that they must be perpendicular. The drop-down clearly explains this.

Comment: the question says "Which of the following must be true?" not "can be true"

Answer (score 1):

The question says which of the following **must** be true.

Note that if $AE$ is perpendicular to $BD$, the conditions given in the question are followed. However, $AE$ may not be perpendicular to $BD$ and $\Delta ABC$ might still be similar to $\Delta EDC$.

The question conditions neither claim nor deny the occurence of perpendicularity; $90°$ is just one of the many possibilities (for $\angle ACB$) and not a **must**-happen event.
[image]
$\angle ACB<90°$ is also possible. If it is still not clear to you try putting $\angle ABC=40°$ and $\angle CAB=80°$. What happens when $\Delta ABC\sim\Delta EDC$?